# I am unable to get the RouteUrl Value in Kendo Grid Client Template. see the code below

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am unable to get the RouteUrl Value in Kendo Grid Client Template. see the code below
for some reason it is show the same page rather than going calling the listing detail page with the Id

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SharedListingViewModel>()
                    .Name("listing-grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {

                        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)                           
                            .ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.RouteUrl("Listing", new { listingId = "#= Id #", SeName = "#= SeName #" }) + "'" + ">Show Details</a>");
  );
 columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(160);

                    })
                    .Editable(x =>
                    {
                        x.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InLine);
                    })
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Scrollable()
                                //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })                                   
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                        .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.Id))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("FavoritesList", "MemberProfile"))
                        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("FavoritesDelete", "MemberProfile"))

                    )
                   )
```

Comment: What is the HTML output generated by the column template? View the source and look for the kendoGrid initialisation script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the issue:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
    .ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.RouteUrl("Listing", new { listingId = "#= Id #", SeName = "#= SeName #" }) + "'" + ">Show Details</a>");
```

);

Think about it this way:

```
var template = "<a href='{0}'>Show Details</a";
template = String.Format(template, Url.RouteUrl("Listing, new {
    listingId = "#= Id #",
    SeName = "#= SeName#"
});
columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
    .ClientTemplate(template);
```

Can you spot the problem?

You're feeding Kendo Template strings as parameters to your Url.RouteUrl method. It will take them as string literals, and probably URL Encode them before returning the hyperlink.

If you change your template to look like this:

```
var template = "<a href='{0}?listingId=#= Id #&SeName=#= SeName #'>Show Details</a>";
```

You'll be on the right track, I'll leave it to your to work out the rest.

Comment: You are right. I also noticed that but the same syntax used work in previous version that is why I was puzzled why it stopped working. Thanks for the help.